# Decomposing a Cartan matrix as the product of a diagonal and symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

I would like to decompose a Cartan matrix $K$ as the product of $D$ and $S$ with $D$ being a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal entries and $S$ a symmetric positive definite matrix. Is there a general algorithm for this? How about a toolbox in say MATLAB to do the work?

Answer (score 0):

A Cartan Matrix is defined as $A_{ab}:=\frac{2(\alpha_a,\alpha_b)}{(\alpha_a,\alpha_a)}$ where $\alpha_a\in\Pi~\forall a$. Let $S_{ab}=(\alpha_a,\alpha_b)$ and $D_{ab}=\delta_{ab}\frac{1}{(\alpha_a,\alpha_a)}$ and we have $A=DS$.